# It skips the first output whenever i print the list, how do i correct this?

Tags: freepascal

Whenever i try to print the list of voters (output) with first entering the information for 5 eligible persons named a, b, c , d and e and the other 5 are not eligible named f, g, h, i, j. it outputs b, c, d, e, f as the valid voters when it should be a, b, c, d, e

```
PROGRAM List_of_Eligible_Voters;
{States whether a person is a valid voter or not}


Const
YOE=2019;


VAR
Felony_Status: string;
Eligibility:ARRAY[1..10] of string;
Name:ARRAY[1..10] OF string;
YOB,Age:integer;
Count:integer;
i:integer;




BEGIN
i:=0;
Count:=0;

     FOR i:= 1 TO 10 DO
     Begin

          Name[i]:='Name';
          Eligibility[i]:='Eligibility';
     End;

          Writeln('Please enter the name of the person.');
          Readln (Name[Count]);
          Writeln ('Please enter the year of birth of the person.');
          Readln (YOB);
          Writeln ('Have the person ever been convicted of a felony?()Answer with yes/no.');
          Readln (Felony_Status);
          While (YOB <> 0) AND (Count<=10) Do
           begin
                Age:= YOE-YOB;
                IF (Age>= 18) AND (Felony_Status = 'no')Then

                   Eligibility[Count]:= 'yes'
                ELSE

                   Eligibility[Count]:= 'no';

                   Writeln('Please enter the name of the person.');
                   Readln (Name[Count]);
                   Writeln ('Please enter the year of birth of the person.');
                   Readln (YOB);
                   Writeln ('Have the person ever been convicted of a felony?()Answer with yes/no.');
                   Readln (Felony_Status);
                   COUNT:=COUNT+1;
          END;
                 Writeln ('List of Eligible Candidates');
                 FOR i:= 1 TO Count DO
                     begin
                     IF  Eligibility[i]= 'yes' THEN
                         Writeln (Name[i], '()is eligible to vote.');

                     END;
                         readln;
END.
```

Comment: If you turn on range and overflow checking and run the code in the debugger, you will find that you access `Eligibility[Count]` with `Count` = 0 , just like @iHazCode says.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using Count as your Index (i) when writing, then Index as your Index when reading. Count is 0 based, and index is 1 based. Have you tried syncing the two up?

Comment: i don't understand what you're saying, could you clarify please?

Comment: Whoops - meant to comment, not answer, but in any case...                   
                                                                                                                  
Though I haven't executed this code yet it would appear you are setting Eligibility[Count] in your WHILE loop. I've noted that Count would be a 1 at this point. Though down below we are printing Eligibility[index] which was initialized at 0. Was this intentional?

Comment: I doubt your teacher taught you that. Because it is wrong. It's time to learn to use a debugger. Once you do you'll find yourself able to solve such problems easily.

Comment: I don't think your teacher taught you that, either. Do as David said, and start debugging. FWIW, debugging is very easy, in Delphi, even in Delphi 7.

Comment: Easy or not easy, debugging is an important skill to have.

Comment: @Bogdan: Sure, but in the case of Delphi, there is no good reason to hesitate, IMO. Debugging in Delphi is far easier and more convenient than using, say, gdb or similar.